# Angular 5 locale data missing

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular5

I use

angular 5.1.2

angular-cli 1.6.2

When I run `ng build --prod`, I get the following error:

[image: Chrome console]

I looked in the docs, and also on SO, but I fail to see what is missing.

**ng-serve runs perfectly**, my pipe is dynamically updated, but on `ng build--prod` I get this error always.

This is how I register `localeDE` in `app.module.ts`

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDE from '@angular/common/locales/de';
registerLocaleData(localeDE);
```

What else is needed for `ng build--prod` to run?

Comment: Have you added that locale in the polyfills file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263717/missing-locale-data-for-the-locale-ru-angular-5

Comment: @jonrsharpe - i have now. No difference. :-)

Comment: @Sajeetharan - I triead also with the ng build --locale de, and I get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Have  not found why it doesn't work with the translate service.
However,
it seems that Angular in-built pipe does support dynamically changing locales. Thanks to [ocombe](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21255#issuecomment-354810659).
My problem with the inbuilt pipe was that I was using (with the setup above)

```
{{ASN.ClosedDateTime  | jsonDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy EEEE HH:mm:ss':currentLanguage}}
```

instead of

```
{{ ASN.ClosedDateTime | jsonDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy EEEE HH:mm:ss':'':currentLanguage }}.
```

I post it just for the case someone else has this typo.